# How can I alter the index of loop for a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I've a list and I want to display the content with index by manually changing the value of index. I've tried to do it in two ways but it is not working.

way 1:

```
x=['hello','how','are','you','hope','you','are','fine','I','am','doing','work','in','python']
for i,item in enumerate(x):
  print (i,item)
  if item == 'are':
    i+=2
```

way 2:

```
x=['hello','how','are','you','hope','you','are','fine','I','am','doing','work','in','python']
for i in xrange(len(x)):
  print x[i]
  if item == 'are':
    i+=2
```

Comment: You can either switch to a `while` loop and increment `i` manually, or call the [next()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function (twice, in your case).

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: Not sure what is the purpose; change the real index of the item or just for your own bookkeeping in one way or another?

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time. Actually I'm new to python so I'm having these types of doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that both `enumerate()` and `xrange()` generate a series of values that is unaffected by external changes to `i`, which is an unconnected variable. Using @efferalgans's suggestion the best way might be to call the `next()` function twice, but this will mean storing a reference to the generator. So you want to do something like this:

```
x=['hello','how','are','you','hope','you','are','fine','I','am','doing','work','in','python']
g = enumerate(x)
for i,item in g:
  print (i,item)
  if item == 'are':
    next(g)
    next(g)
```

from which I see the result

```
0 hello
1 how
2 are
5 you
6 are
9 am
10 doing
11 work
12 in
13 python
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I'm new to python so I'm getting these doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a while loop. It's the simplest, clearest and most flexible solution:

```
i = 0
while i < len(x):
    print x[i]
    if x[i] == 'are':
        i+=1
    i += 1
```

As you can see, looping over a string is simple and you are completely free to change the index on the fly -- `i` is just a normal variable. It's not clear what your code was actually meant to do, so the above does what your code would (presumably) have done if it worked: It will skip the word that *follows* the word "are".

Comment: Welcome. Since you're just getting started, let me add a suggestion: Switch to Python 3 today. It has several important advantages over Python 2.7, and it makes no sense to invest time on learning an obsolete version of the language.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I'll try to shift to python 3